# Index an array with condition

Tags: filtering, list-manipulation, indexing

I have a list like the following:

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 1}};
```

I would like to select those entries whose second elements are greater than 2, therefore the result should be:

```
newlist = {{1,11},{2,7},{7,9}}
```

I know how to doit separately with:

```
Select[list, #[[2]] > 2 &][[All, 1]]
Select[list, #[[2]] > 2 &][[All, 2]]
```

but in that way I get {1, 2, 7} and {11, 7, 9}. How could I join this two output
to get: newlist = {{1,11},{2,7},{7,9}}

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Select[list, #[[2]] > 2 &]
(*{{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {7, 9}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 1}};
```

Pre-define pattern for better readability

```
p = {_, a_} /; a <= 2;
```

Now there are many possibilities ...

```
DeleteCases[list, p];

list /. p :> Nothing;

Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {p}];

Delete[Position[list, p]] @ list;
```

All return

{{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {7, 9}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 1}};
```

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, {_, b_ /; b <= 2} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {7, 9}}*)
```

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, Map[#[[2]] > 2 &]@#] &@list

(*{{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {7, 9}}*)
```